# How to accept string literal types in function and then map it to key-value pair in typescript?

Tags: typescript

consider below function which accepts a slack channel name as parameter then find its corresponding `channelId` and post a message.

```js
type slackChannel =
  | "signups"
  | "alerts"
  | "errors"
  | "deployments"

const slack = {
  signups: "C015P5CAXPY",
  alerts: "C021TN73GBE",
  errors: "C021VLK4U0M",
  deployments: "C0214CASA76"
};

export async function sendSlackMessage(
  text: string,
  channelName: slackChannel
): Promise<void> {
  const slackClient = new WebClient("SLACK_KEY");
  
  await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
    text: text,
    channel: channelId, //need to find channelId from channelName
  });
}
```

one way to get `channelId` is to use switch case or if-else loop and map ids to channel name.

other way is to use `[]` and pass channelId to slack object e.g. `channel: slack[channelId]` but it requires to maintain both `slack` object and `slackChannel`

one more way is to use `slack` object as new parameter for `channelId` e.g. `slack.signups` but it'd require caller function to first import `slack` object to pass it to function. I prefer string literals as those aren't required to be imported.

is there any better way to accept string literal `channelName` parameter and then map it to ids without loops? Maybe using some typescript concepts like ‎Pick<Type, Keys> · ‎Omit<Type, Keys> · ‎Extract<Type, Union> etc?

Comment: Whats the problem in using `const channelId = slack[channelName];` in your current code ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using `Extract`

```js
type slackChannel = Extract<keyof typeof slack,string>;

const slack = {
  signups: "C015P5CAXPY",
  alerts: "C021TN73GBE",
  errors: "C021VLK4U0M",
  deployments: "C0214CASA76"
};
export async function sendSlackMessage(
  text: string,
  channelName: slackChannel
): Promise<void> {
  const slackClient = new WebClient("SLACK_KEY");
  
  await slackClient.chat.postMessage({
    text: text,
    channel: slack[channelName],
  });
}
```